# compute difference between 2 ranked columns in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to find the difference between 2 columns in tableau. The catch though here is that each column is ranked based on a value. The difference i need is between these 2 ranked columns

The rank is computed using the table calculations rank function. Attaching the picture for more information[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming "current" and "prior" are calculated fields.

Just create a new calculated field, here I'll call it "Result". In this field just minus your one from the other so:

```
  [Current - Prior]
```

Then pull this new field into your measures values on your sheet.